# Already Defined Error when building with gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-appcompat

I imported an old project from ANT to Gradle. I included all libraries and tride build but i have problem:

```
 E:\gradle\DriverClient\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-wallet\7.8.0\res\values\wallet_colors.xml
    Error:(2) Attribute "titleTextStyle" has already been defined
    Error:(2) Attribute "subtitleTextStyle" has already been defined
    Error:(2) Attribute "divider" has already been defined
    Error:(2) Attribute "background" has already been defined
    Error:(2) Attribute "backgroundSplit" has already been defined
    Error:(2) Attribute "navigationMode" has already been defined
    Error:(2) Attribute "displayOptions" has already been defined
  .............................
```

I do not understand what is wrong.  Here are my Gradle dependencies -

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.5'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
}
```

Comment: if yuo downwote answer Arguments please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can't** use appcompat library and ActionBarSherlock together because they are using the same attrs.

I suggest you **using the appcompat library** since abs [was deprecated](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/) about two years ago,not updated and out of mantenaince.

Comment: I understand and know. but I need to use that old. I'm still just a project to translate gradle and I do not make it possible to alter

Comment: @ip696 In any case it is the reason and they can't work together.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
```

Hope it helps :)